# Express Route-level Middlewares acting like App-level middlewares

Tags: node.js, express

I am trying to understand the Route-level middlewares in Express.

Following is my code:

```
const Express = require('express');
const app = Express();

// Start - Middlewares
const m1 = (request, response, next) => {
  request.m1 = 'm1';
  return next();
};
const m2 = (request, response, next) => {
  request.m2 = 'm2';
  return next();
};
const m3 = (request, response, next) => {
  request.m3 = 'm3';
  return next();
};
// End - Middlewares

// Start - Routes
const Route1 = Express.Router();
const Route2 = Express.Router();
const Route3 = Express.Router();

Route1.use(m1);
Route1.get('/m1', (request, response, next) => {
  const { m1, m2, m3 } = request;
  return response.json({ m1, m2, m3 });
});

Route2.use(m2);
Route2.get('/m2', (request, response, next) => {
  const { m1, m2, m3 } = request;
  return response.json({ m1, m2, m3 });
});

Route3.use(m3);
Route3.get('/m3', (request, response, next) => {
  const { m1, m2, m3 } = request;
  return response.json({ m1, m2, m3 });
});
// End - Routes

// App Setup
app.use('/v1', Route1);
app.use('/v1', Route2);
app.use('/v1', Route3);

app.listen('3232', '0.0.0.0', () => console.log('Running app'));
```

So, the expected output is:

`http://localhost:3232/v1/m1` should return `{m1: 'm1'}`

`http://localhost:3232/v1/m2` should return `{m2: 'm2'}`

`http://localhost:3232/v1/m3` should return `{m3: 'm3'}`

The actual (& unexpected) output is:

`http://localhost:3232/v1/m1` should return `{m1: 'm1'}`

`http://localhost:3232/v1/m2` should return `{m1: 'm1', m2: 'm2'}`

`http://localhost:3232/v1/m3` should return `{m1: 'm1', m2: 'm2', m3: 'm3'}`

Hence, it seems like, the middlewares are getting applied as we move down the routes configured with `app.use`.

What is the correct way of setting up Route-level middlewares? Also, here the code is shared as a single file. But in reality, each component has its own directory - middlewares, routes, controllers, etc.

My basepath is going to be /v1 and hence it is common for all the routes.

Comment: When you call `GET /v1/m3`, the route will match with `/v1/*` (`app.use('/v1', Route1);`), `/v1/*` (`app.use('/v1', Route2);`) and `/v1/*` (`app.use('/v1', Route3);`) then it goes through 3 middleware. Have to many ways to avoid this, ex: `Route1.get('/m1',  m1, (request, response, next)...` instead of `Route1.use(m1);`

Comment: But, if I have `Route1.get('/m1')`, `Route1.get('/m11')`, `Route1.get('/m12')` then in that case, the m1 middleware will be repeated. I want clean code without repeating myself.

Comment: Just use one `Route`

Comment: There has to be a logical separation between the Route1, Route2 and Route3. These are all doing different things.

Comment: I guess the main difference comes from handlers. `app.use('/v1/m1', Route1);`

Comment: That is correct. I can't have just /v1 in the routes. So, I am using the middlewares like you suggested. With each route of the Routers.